# What is the value of i if nums size is not equal to capacity?

Tags: c, data-structures, iteration, max-heap

I am studying max heap and in it there is a createheap function. In it , there is a for loop like this

```
    for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        h->arr[i] = nums[i];
    }
```

if size of nums is not equal to capacity then does the variable i gives the size of nums or is it equal to capacity? (the for loop runs till *i* is equal to capacity ,right?)

Comment: You really need to tag questions with the relevant programming language.  Assuming that this is C code, the size of `nums` is not being considered; if `capacity` is larger than the size, garbage will be read from memory past the end of the array.  Other languages might throw an exception once `i` goes out of range.

Comment: @jasonharper My doubt is if size of nums is less than the size of capacity then, does for loop runs till i is equal to capacity or not

Comment: Why would it stop any earlier?  The loop has no stopping condition that has anything to do with `nums`.  Of course, the whole program might crash once you start accessing memory beyond the actual end of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...the for loop runs till i is equal to capacity ,right?

~~No.~~ Maybe.

When `capacity` exceeds "the size of nums", once `i` is equal to "the size of nums", further iterations lead to [*undefined behavior* (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Anything may happen, including executing until `i == capacity`, crashing due to accessing memory it doesn't own, [replacing your hotel with a football stadium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794), etc.